# Error: All list elements must be lists themselves: Error in using spread_draws function in tidybayes

Tags: r, bayesian, rstan, hierarchical-bayesian, brms

In playing around with the tidybayes package (I replicated the data from the code simulated in the vignette: http://mjskay.github.io/tidybayes/articles/tidybayes.html), I continue to stumble onto the error: Error: All list elements must be lists themselves when using the spread_draws function (or any other functions in the tidybayes, for that matter). Here is the simulated data from the vignette:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidybayes)
library(brms)

set.seed(5)
n = 10
n_condition = 5
ABC =
  tibble(
    condition = rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), n),
    response = rnorm(n * 5, c(0,1,2,1,-1), 0.5)
  )
```

Here is the code for fitting the model:

```
m = brm(
  response ~ (1|condition), 
  data = ABC, 
  prior = c(
    prior(normal(0, 1), class = Intercept),
    prior(student_t(3, 0, 1), class = sd),
    prior(student_t(3, 0, 1), class = sigma)
  ),
  control = list(adapt_delta = .99)
)
```

But, even in trying to use the get_variables function, I get the same error as mentioned above. Has anyone else had a similar problem or been able to solve this one?

Here is the session info.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] tidybayes_3.0.1   see_0.6.7         bayestestR_0.11.0 semTools_0.5-5   
 [5] lavaan_0.6-9      HDInterval_0.2.2  brms_2.15.0       Rcpp_1.0.6       
 [9] ggsignif_0.6.2    reshape2_1.4.4    ggsci_2.9         psych_2.0.12     
[13] jtools_2.1.3      magrittr_2.0.1    extrafont_0.17    ggthemes_4.2.4   
[17] forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.4       purrr_0.3.4      
[21] tidyr_1.1.2       tibble_3.0.6      tidyverse_1.3.0   gridExtra_2.3    
[25] ggpubr_0.4.0      ggplot2_3.3.5     readr_1.4.0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] utf8_1.1.4           tidyselect_1.1.0     lme4_1.1-26         
  [4] htmlwidgets_1.5.3    grid_4.0.3           munsell_0.5.0       
  [7] codetools_0.2-18     statmod_1.4.35       DT_0.18             
 [10] miniUI_0.1.1.1       withr_2.4.1          Brobdingnag_1.2-6   
 [13] colorspace_2.0-0     knitr_1.31           rstudioapi_0.13     
 [16] stats4_4.0.3         Rttf2pt1_1.3.9       bayesplot_1.8.1     
 [19] labeling_0.4.2       emmeans_1.5.4        rstan_2.21.2        
 [22] mnormt_2.0.2         farver_2.0.3         datawizard_0.2.0.1  
 [25] bridgesampling_1.1-2 coda_0.19-4          vctrs_0.3.6         
 [28] generics_0.1.0       TH.data_1.0-10       xfun_0.25           
 [31] R6_2.5.0             markdown_1.1         gamm4_0.2-6         
 [34] projpred_2.0.2       assertthat_0.2.1     promises_1.2.0.1    
 [37] scales_1.1.1         multcomp_1.4-16      debugme_1.1.0       
 [40] gtable_0.3.0         processx_3.5.2       sandwich_3.0-0      
 [43] rlang_0.4.10         splines_4.0.3        rstatix_0.7.0       
 [46] extrafontdb_1.0      checkmate_2.0.0      broom_0.7.7         
 [49] inline_0.3.17        yaml_2.2.1           abind_1.4-5         
 [52] modelr_0.1.8         threejs_0.3.3        crosstalk_1.1.1     
 [55] backports_1.2.1      httpuv_1.5.5         rsconnect_0.8.18    
 [58] tensorA_0.36.2       tools_4.0.3          ellipsis_0.3.1      
 [61] posterior_1.0.1      ggridges_0.5.3       plyr_1.8.6          
 [64] base64enc_0.1-3      ps_1.5.0             prettyunits_1.1.1   
 [67] zoo_1.8-8            haven_2.3.1          fs_1.5.0            
 [70] data.table_1.14.0    ggdist_3.0.0         openxlsx_4.2.3      
 [73] colourpicker_1.1.0   reprex_1.0.0         tmvnsim_1.0-2       
 [76] mvtnorm_1.1-1        matrixStats_0.58.0   hms_1.0.0           
 [79] shinyjs_2.0.0        mime_0.10            evaluate_0.14       
 [82] arrayhelpers_1.1-0   xtable_1.8-4         shinystan_2.5.0     
 [85] rio_0.5.16           readxl_1.3.1         rstantools_2.1.1    
 [88] compiler_4.0.3       V8_3.4.2             crayon_1.4.1        
 [91] minqa_1.2.4          StanHeaders_2.21.0-7 htmltools_0.5.1.1   
 [94] mgcv_1.8-34          later_1.1.0.1        RcppParallel_5.1.4  
 [97] lubridate_1.7.10     DBI_1.1.1            dbplyr_2.1.0        
[100] MASS_7.3-54          boot_1.3-27          Matrix_1.3-2        
[103] car_3.0-10           cli_2.5.0            parallel_4.0.3      
[106] insight_0.14.4       igraph_1.2.6         pkgconfig_2.0.3     
[109] foreign_0.8-81       xml2_1.3.2           svUnit_1.0.6        
[112] dygraphs_1.1.1.6     pbivnorm_0.6.0       estimability_1.3    
[115] rvest_1.0.0          distributional_0.2.2 callr_3.7.0         
[118] digest_0.6.27        rmarkdown_2.10       cellranger_1.1.0    
[121] curl_4.3             shiny_1.6.0          gtools_3.8.2        
[124] nloptr_1.2.2.2       lifecycle_1.0.0      nlme_3.1-152        
[127] jsonlite_1.7.2       carData_3.0-4        fansi_0.4.2         
[130] pillar_1.5.0         lattice_0.20-41      loo_2.4.1           
[133] fastmap_1.1.0        httr_1.4.2           pkgbuild_1.2.0      
[136] survival_3.2-11      glue_1.4.2           xts_0.12.1          
[139] zip_2.1.1            shinythemes_1.2.0    pander_0.6.3        
[142] stringi_1.5.3
```

If you need any other information or if I oversaw providing something, please let me know!

Many thanks for your help and all the best.

Comment: Hi, my session keeps crashing if I try to fit the model as it's specified, so I can't reproduce your error :/

Comment: You have the package brms loaded, right? My session has never crashed while fitting a brm model...odd...

Comment: Yes it's loaded, although when calling `brms`, there is a compilation step, which finishes at some point: `Compiling Stan program...
sh: clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13: command not found
The NEXT version of Stan will not be able to pre-process your Stan program. [...]`. The session crash comes when MCMC sampling starts: `Start sampling`. Probably related to incorrect installation of some dependencies? I am using MacOS and RStudio.

Comment: Maybe you can fall back and try using an earlier version of `rstan`? I think 2.19.3 was the last version -- there have been a few comments in other forums saying that reverting to an older version gets it running again, and the `brms` package with it.

Comment: From your sessionInfo() output you have a number of older versions of tidybayes dependencies, including tibble, vctrs, and posterior. Can you update your packages (e.g. `update.packages(ask = FALSE)`) and try again?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. It seems to be a bug in the recent version 3.0.1. If you fall back on the previous version, your code should work.

`devtools::install_version("tidybayes", version = "3.0.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`

I've posted the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/mjskay/tidybayes/issues/289

Comment: What a life saver! It worked, many thanks for your help and for reporting the issue.

Comment: As @Matthew suggests in response to the GutHub issue I opened (https://github.com/mjskay/tidybayes/issues/289), the problem is probably not with `tidybayes` 3.0.1 but rather with some depedency that is not fully updated. So, when you get a chance, I recommend trying what he suggested in his comment.

Comment: Just updated my packages and now brms isn't running anymore... I was afraid this would happen, brms keeps throwing the error: Error in Module(module, mustStart = TRUE) : 
  function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp' ... Not entirely sure why this is becoming a problem...

Comment: I would just try a fresh install of brms and all its dependencies.

Comment: Reinstalling `brms` did the trick for me when I had the exact same issue.